# How can I optimise a joined query which runs on 130,000 rows?

Tags: mysql, performance

I'm using the following SQL statement:

```
SELECT
  SUM(t.Points) AS `Points`,
  CONCAT(s.Firstname, " ", s.Surname) AS `Name`
FROM transactions t
INNER JOIN student s
  ON t.Recipient_ID = s.Frog_ID
GROUP BY t.Recipient_ID
```

The query takes **21 seconds** to run. Bizarrely, even if I `LIMIT 0, 30` it *still* takes **20.7** seconds to run!

If I run an `EXPLAIN` on this statement, the results are as follows:

```
id  select_type table   type    possible_keys   key     key_len     ref     rows        Extra
1   SIMPLE      s       ALL     PRIMARY         NULL    NULL        NULL    877         Using temporary; Using filesort
1   SIMPLE      t       ALL     NULL            NULL    NULL        NULL    135140      Using where
```

---

A transaction takes the following form:

```
Transaction_ID  Datetime    Giver_ID    Recipient_ID    Points  Category_ID     Reason
1               2011-09-07  36754       34401           5       6               Gave excellent feedback on the new student noteboo...
```

There are **130,000 rows** in the `transactions` table.

---

A student takes the following form:

```
Frog_ID UPN             Firstname   Surname     Intake_Year
101234  K929221234567   Madeup      Student     2010
```

There are **835 rows** in the `student` table.

---

**Indexes**

[image: transactions indexes]

[image: student indexes]

---

Is there a way I can make this query more efficient?

Comment: What indexes do you have?

Comment: Specifically, do you have an index on the transaction.Recipient_ID column?

Comment: I've updated my OP - sorry, thought the `EXPLAIN` might suffice (my lack of knowledge).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You both join using `Recepient_ID` and group by it, yet it's not indexed, so I assume this is the problem.

Try to add `transactions.Recepient_ID` as an index.

Comment: That's fantastic - reduced the query to 1.5 seconds. Is there anything else you can suggest to reduce it further or is that the best I'll get?

Comment: Spend some time thinking about why someone would ever want to look at *all* the data at one time.

Comment: Of course you're right @symcbean. I shall take that thought exactly to a new question.